# Can I create a P2PK tx?

Tags: raw-transaction, p2pk

Is it still possible to send to a pub key directly?

How would I construct such a tx in raw hex, and would the mempool accept it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is still possible, and quite a few p2pk outputs still show up in the blockchain. [d3d3b3545712d2eec3c0fcc35c0e34cf34b6ae92ca86c1d5e6cc5b3d59692273](https://blockstream.info/tx/d3d3b3545712d2eec3c0fcc35c0e34cf34b6ae92ca86c1d5e6cc5b3d59692273?expand) is an example of a transaction from this year that contains 10 p2pk outputs.

If you can find a wallet that still supports p2pk, that would probably be your best option for sending such a transaction. But basically, this is the raw hex for the transaction referenced above. The first ten outputs are all p2pk.

```
01000000

01

26708707719ad3e0fc9412efcbe92c2d15ee01e9ad6fce8538cc738624208350
0b000000
6a4730440220118a0f02c2080f0a6a0f5e58b17f6d12fef4d32277fc816603557767b27bb2be02205ca1e44cefe79580330271b764ba1b1798048af8872eaaed1ce0138edaa0f0d80121037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740
ffffffff

0b

8813000000000000
2321037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740ac

8813000000000000
2321037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740ac

8813000000000000
2321037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740ac

8813000000000000
2321037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740ac

8813000000000000
2321037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740ac

8813000000000000
2321037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740ac

8813000000000000
2321037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740ac

8813000000000000
2321037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740ac

8813000000000000
2321037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740ac

8813000000000000
2321037c394f2adceafcdc5e429218f410f164a80918a185becf7cb314b120dd0cb740ac

11b7190000000000
1976a9147ca88db7ef2b1a164fe5f5be3a2c94265d9e002688ac

00000000
```

If it is formatted correctly, the mempool would probably accept it. This transaction type is not used as often anymore, but there are still hundreds of them that are accepted.